YouTube Data API Playlist Update status.privacyStatus not working
When we use YouTube Data API Playlist Update to update the status.privacyStatus of a YouTube playlist, it fails with the unexpectedPart error.
Part : Status
Request Body :
{
  "id": "PLI4NMKWV7cqUHnHhLA_aWErP-MlVIcWqJ",
  "status": {
    "privacyStatus": "private"
  }
}

Response :
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "'{0}'",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "'{0}'",
        "domain": "youtube.part",
        "reason": "unexpectedPart",
        "location": "part",
        "locationType": "parameter"
      }
    ]
  }
}

The following works though :
Part : Snippet, Status
Request Body :
{
  "id": "PLI4NMKWV7cqUHnHhLA_aWErP-MlVIcWqJ",
"snippet" : {
    "title": "playListTitle"
}
  "status": {
    "privacyStatus": "private"
  }
}

Seems to be a bug, hugh?
